# How to mount LVM Volume group to a directory?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, lvm

I created one Volume Group via LVM.

```
VG                  #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree  
main_storage          2   0   0 wz--n- 149,05g 149,05g
```

This group consists of two physical HDDs.

```
/dev/sdb  [74,53 GiB] LVM physical volume
/dev/sdc  [74,53 GiB] LVM physical volume
```

How do I can mount directory to this volume group? Or if this group has some default path, how do I can find out it?

The idea is to have one directory in which the data would be stored. And on this directory would be mounted hard drives. And when the memory runs out, I would add new hard drives and get more space for this directory by extendig my volume group.

And how I understand I can do it with LVM by creating volume group, mounting it to a directory and extending it in case if free space of this volume group running out? Is it right?

Is the LVM is a right tool to do it? If not, tell me pls how do I can do something like it.

Thanks in advance. Sorry if my answer has some wrong/bad descriptions and terms.

Comment: This seems like a variation on the classic "I want something like a Windows D: drive" that many new users try. If you are a new user, you may try several partitioning schemes, no need to lock yourself into any particular one yet. Also, a downside of LVM is that if you have 10TB of storage, you need 10TB of backups. Hard drives DO die, taking all their precious, irreplaceable data with them.

Comment: I agree with @user535733 and on top of that: yes, you're correct if you substitute "Directory"  for "Mount Point".  Read the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.pdf) for more information or just put `/home` (the mount point) on the volume group and then all of `/home` will never run out of disk space!  **0:-)**